# Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following problem.

This error persisting in accompanying me

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\certificado\functions.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\certificado\index.php(11): get_info_from_email('amanda_pandoka@...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\certificado\functions.php on line 49

In the code below I can not understand the error. Can someone help me?

```
    function connect() {
    $socket = new PDO('mysql:host=' . @$host . ';dbname=' . @$nomedobancodedados,
        @$usuario, @$senha);
    $socket->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $socket;
}

function get_info_from_email($email) {

    if (!$email)
        return false;

    global $db;

    $sql = "
        SELECT
            id,
            name,
            email,
            type,
            data,
            file
        FROM
            attendee
        WHERE 1=1
            AND email = '{$email}'
    ";
    if ($info = $db->query($sql))
        return false;

    if ($info = $info->fetchAll())
        return false;

    return $info;

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Continue like this

```
 function get_info_from_email($email) {
if (!$email) {
    return false;
}

global $db;

$sql = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        id,
        name,
        email,
        type,
        data,
        file
    FROM
        attendee
    WHERE 1=1
        AND email = :email
");
print_r($db->errorInfo());
// return false if the query cannot be executed
if (!$sql->execute(array(':email' => $info))) {
    return false;
}

// return false if there was an **error** retrieving the query results
if (($info = $sql->fetchAll()) === false) {
    return false;
}

return $info;
```

}

Comment: `array(':email' => $info)` should be `array(':email' => $email)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($info = $db->query($sql))
    return false;
```

This says: if the result of `$db->query($sql)` can be stored in `$info` and is not something like `false`, `null` or an empty string or array, stop now and return `false`. So basically, if your query executes successfully and properly returns a `PDOStatement` with results in it, your function stops here.

```
if ($info = $info->fetchAll())
    return false;
```

This is where you're getting the error. The fact that this code is reached at all means that the query failed to execute (otherwise, it would have returned `false` earlier). So basically, you're calling `fetchAll()` on `false`. Try to see what the error is here (do a `print_r($db->errorInfo());` before this `if`-statement)

By the way, this `if`-statement will also cause your function to return `false` if the `fetchAll()` call was **successful**, which is probably not what you want. Additionally, by using `$db->query()` directly with the email address provided in the function call, you're leaving your code open to possible SQL injection attacks. As a rule, **never** trust any variable if you don't have 100% control over what's in it. You should use a prepared statement instead.

As another rule, **always** use curly braces on code blocks (`if`/`elseif`/`else`, `for`/`foreach`/`while`/`do`, `try`/`catch`/`finally`), because then you don't need to think about them anymore if you someday decide that the code block should do two things instead of one, and it's easier to debug code if you can visually see exactly what your code is trying to do.

This code (not tested) should work the way you want:

```
function get_info_from_email($email) {
    if (!$email) {
        return false;
    }

    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("
        SELECT
            id,
            name,
            email,
            type,
            data,
            file
        FROM
            attendee
        WHERE 1=1
            AND email = :email
    ");

    // return false if the query cannot be executed
    if (!$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email))) {
        return false;
    }

    // return false if there was an **error** retrieving the query results
    if (($info = $stmt->fetchAll()) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return $info;
}
```

Comment: I made a print_r($db->errorInfo()); and it with the code that you put returned the error 

Array ([0] => 00000 [1] => [2] =>)

Comment: That means there was no error. What does it return with your original code?

Comment: Returns that the email could not be found in the database!

Comment: OK, so does the new function return the correct results then?

Comment: Yes according to
     Print_r ($ db-> errorInfo ());
It returns a result, it just does not conflict the database to generate a certificate with the extension GD

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you just said or what this function has to do with certificates or the GD extension. If you call `get_info_from_email()` with an email address that exists in your database, does it return the data from the `attendee` table? And does it return `false` if the email address does not exist?

Comment: It returns a message that was previously specified for emails that do not exist in the database. Even though the email exists, it returns that it does not exist.

Comment: Sounds like there is no column "email" in the "attendee" table. Can you copy/paste the exact error message?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: info in C:\xampp\htdocs\certificado\functions.php on line 76

Comment: Line 76 on 
if (!$sql->execute(array($email => $info))) {
        return false;
    }

Comment: That's not how that array should look. It should be `array(':email' => $email)` -- if you use the function I posted with the modified query and a prepared statement.

Comment: Even with your code, continues the error on line 76

Comment: You must have copy/pasted my code wrong. I just tried the exact code in my answer in a [test file](https://gist.github.com/rickdenhaan/6a32a360acc129f20dec023e5c996308), and it works without a problem. Can you update your question to include the code **exactly** as you have it now?